# Creating 2D array with fill method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create two dimensional array using `fill` functions. It's looks like this:

```
let map = new Array(3)
            .fill(new Array(3)
                .fill(0));
```

Problem appears when I try to set one value at specific index:

```
map[1][1] = 1;
```

I expect to have result:

```
[[0, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0],[0, 0, 0]]
```

But I receive this:

```
[[0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 0]]
```

It looks like all this subarrays referencing to one array but why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `fill(new Array(3))` first makes a new array and then fills the array with that so each element points to the same array reference. When you change one, it's reflected in all of them.

You could use `Array.from()` for the outer arrays, which takes a function. This will allow you to make a new array for each one:

```js
let map = Array.from(Array(3), () => new Array(3).fill(0)) 

map[1][1] = 1;
console.log(map)
```

Here it will call the function for each element insuring that that a unique array is made for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
maps = new Array(3)
            .fill().map(u => new Array(3).fill(0));

maps[1][1] = 1;
```